# keras json model doesn't giving me the predictions correctly but h5 model giving mostly correct prediction

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, machine-learning, keras

I trained a CNN Model in keras to predict the gestures of a match refry and give the points to the Players. I have collected data from live matches and trained the model. When I am using h5 file model with cv2 library then It giving me the mostly accurate result but when I am integration the Json model to frontend using @tensorflow/tfjs then It giving me the same predictions

```
  const predict = async () => {
    const video = videoRef?.current?.video; // getting live video from Camera
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    const input = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);
    const resizedInput = tf.image.resizeBilinear(input, [64, 64]);
    const batchedInput = resizedInput.expandDims(0);
    const prediction = model.predict(batchedInput);
    const value = prediction.dataSync();
    const predictedIndex = value.indexOf(Math.max(...value));
    const predictedClassLabel = classLabels[predictedIndex];
    setPredictedScore(predictedClassLabel); // set Prediction Array in State
    tf.dispose(batchedInput);
    tf.dispose(prediction);
  };
  useAnimationFrame(predict, 5000);

  const loadModel = async () => {
    try {
      let model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);
      setModel(model);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Above is the Implementation Code of Model in React Js. In the above code we get live feed from camera and getting prediction in the form of array.